# Proof of FTA from Hatcher

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-verification

This is the proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra (FTA) given in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology textbook (I have underlined the relevant part):

[image: Proof of FTA]

> Could someone explain why $r$ needs to be bigger than $1$ for the proof to work?

I don't see where the assumption $r>1$ is used in the proof. I am sure I am missing something obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for the inequality
$$
(|a_1|+\cdots+|a_n|)|z^{n-1}|\geq |a_1z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n|
$$
i.e.
$$
|a_1z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n|\leq|a_1||z|^{n-1}+\cdots+|a_n|\leq |a_1||z|^{n-1}+\cdots+|a_n||z|^{n-1}.
$$

Comment: [facepalm...] Thanks :)